# In PostScript, define a procedure to define other procedures

Tags: postscript

The purpose of this question is to understand PostScript a bit better from a programming perspective. The goal described below is just an example used for illustration.

In the PostScript language, I can define a procedure to set the current graphics color as follows:

```
/cRED { 1 0 0 setrgbcolor } def  % define a procedure to set the color to red.
```

I was wondering if there was a way to define a procedure that would define other color procedures. Assume that such a procedure called `cdef` were defined. I could use it as follows:

```
/cRED 1 0 0 cdef
```

This should have the same effect as the previous definition of cRED.
The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to "capture" the literal value of items on the stack in a procedure passed to `def`.

I tried the following:

```
/cdef { /B exch def /G exch def /R exch def { R G B setrgbcolor } bind def } def
/cRED 1 0 0  cdef
/cGRN 0 1 0  cdef 
/cBLU 0 0 1  cdef
```

My expectation was that by using `bind` the values of `R` `G` and `B` would be captured literally. I.e. I was expecting the code above to be equivalent to this:

```
/cRED { 1 0 0 setrgbcolor } def
/cGRN { 0 1 0 setrgbcolor } def
/cBLU { 0 0 1 setrgbcolor } def
```

Unfortunately the actual result is that `cRED` `cGRN` and `cBLU` all set the color to **blue**. This is because `cRED` `cGRN` and `cBLU` are still dependent on the `R` `G` and `B` objects (which are globals). And so the color is blue for all because `cBLU` defined last, setting `R` `G` and `B`. Apparently `bind` didn't work the way I expected.

Is there a way to define `cdef` to achieve this? The crux of the issue is being able to pop a value off the stack and store it literally using `def`. E.g. something like this *pseudo-code*:

```
/cdef { { $ $ $ setrgbcolor } bind def } def
```

Where `$` woudl be replaced with the literal value of the item at the top of the stack when cdef is being evaluated. So `/cCYN 0 1 1 cdef` is evaluated as `/cCYN { 0 1 1 setrgbcolor } bind def`

Is there some operator that fulfills the purpose of the `$` as described above? The operators `pop`, `=`, and `index` are close, but don't seem to work. 
In addition, the use of *Immediately Evaluated Names* (e.g. `//name`) seems promising, but they seem to be evaluated even before `cdef` is executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it by "rolling" the parameters in place instead of assigning them

```
/cdef { [ 4 1 roll /setrgbcolor load ] cvx bind def } def
```

In that way, when the `] cvx bind def` inside is executed it finds on the operand stack

```
/YourNameForTheProcedure
[ (i.e. mark)
your three parameters (the mark has been rolled below them)
the setrgbcolor operator (or procedure?)
```

Then the closing `]` will make an array out of the three numbers and the setrgbcolor, that will be made into a procedure by `cvx`.

**Note: Then** You have to pass the r,g,b parameters in the correct order:

```
/CR 1 0 0 cdef
/CG 0 1 0 cdef
/CB 0 0 1 cdef
```

Comment: Thanks! `roll` and `cvx` were both new to me. There are some adequate online getting-started guides for postscript, but they are all very basic. Adobe's PLRM is thorough, but harder to navigate and of couse filled mostly with information ancillary to the actual programming language. Do you have a good recommendation for a good online reference, preferably with some detailed examples?

Comment: Surely agree that PLRM is not a good tutorial. Have a rough read of the command reference there and, when you're programming it yourself, with a focus first on the basic programming constructs like operand stack (roll, exch, dup etc), dictstack, datatypes (cvx/s/i etc)

Answer (score 5):

Stefan's answer is probably the best and simplest way for this case. But there are many more ways to construct procedures in postscript.

Since you know the exact number of elements, you can skip the stack juggling with the mark and do it like this:

```
/cdef { /setrgbcolor load 4 array astore cvx def } def
```

And a more complicated way might be useful for more complicated functions. You can define the arguments and substitute definitions into a string template. I think this is what you were striving toward with the immediately-evaluated names. Executing the string yield the procedure body, but the scanning and *evaluation* is performed at run-time.

```
/cdef { 
    3 dict begin
        { b g r } { exch def } forall
        ({ //r //g //b setrgbcolor }) cvx exec
    end
    def
} def
```

And another way, which is perhaps clumsy but very flexible.

```
/curry {
    /exec cvx
    3 array astore cvx
} def

/cdef {
    {setrgbcolor} 3{curry}repeat
    def
} def
```

This results in this procedure being defined for the values 1 2 3:

```
{ 1 { 2 { 3 { setrgbcolor } exec } exec } exec }
```

So, perhaps some slight loss of micro-efficiency. But it could be used for all sorts of things.

Comment: Kinda lambda expressions in postscript, cool, never thought about that.